# Jupyter kernel doesn't use Poetry environment

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, python-poetry

I'm trying to install a Jupyter kernel for my poetry environment, but it seems like the kernel gets my base conda environment. Here's what I'm trying:

```
poetry env list
>ENV_NAME-HASH-py3.9 (Activated)

poetry run which python
>/Users/myusername/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/ENV_NAME-HASH-py3.9/bin/python

poetry run ipython kernel install --name=ENV_NAME
>Installed kernelspec ENV_NAME in /Users/myusername/Library/Jupyter/kernels/ENV_NAME
```

Then if I open a Jupyter with this kernel I don't get the libraries that should be installed. Checking the Python version I get:

```
!which python
/Users/myusername/opt/anaconda3/bin/python
```

Any help appreaciated!

Answer (score 1):

did you try to activate your environement first ? (using `source {path to env}/bin/activate` ? if so, can you try installing the ipykernel directly : `poetry run python -m ipykernel install --user --name myname`

Answer (score 1):

Bonjour, I come tardily but I think I have your solution.

If you just want to use your currently configured Poetry environment in VSCode with your `.ipynb` notebooks, you can do this for example:

1. **Create a new project with Poetry:**

   ```bash
   poetry new test_ipynb
   cd test_ipynb
   ```
2. **Use a specific Python version with your environment:**

   ```bash
   poetry env use 3.12
   ```
3. **Add `ipykernel` to your environment:**

   ```bash
   poetry add ipykernel
   ```
4. **Check your environment's executable path:**

   ```bash
   poetry env info
   ```

   Example output:

   ```
   /home/guillaume/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/test-ipynb-pH8Jwd_U-py3.12/bin/python
   ```
5. **Open your project in VSCode:**

   ```bash
   code .
   ```

Then, in VSCode:

- Install [Jupyter extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-toolsai.jupyter)
- In the top right, click on the **Select Kernel**.

  [image: choose Python environment]
- Choose **"Python Environments"**.

  [image: Python Environments]
- And select the environment you got from the `env info` command.

  [image: select the environment]

This should allow you to use your Poetry-managed virtual environment directly within VSCode for Jupyter notebooks.

**Additionally**, if you want to use Jupyter or JupyterLab, just follow the steps above and add:

```bash
poetry add jupyter
poetry run jupyter notebook
# For JupyterLab
poetry add jupyterlab
poetry run jupyter lab
```

This ensures that your development environment is consistent across different tools and platforms, leveraging Poetry's dependency management and virtual environment capabilities directly within VSCode for Jupyter notebooks.

Comment: For this solution to work, you also might need to set some vsc configuration variable. In my case the list of poetry envs was not appearing when trying to choose a kernel.  I set python.defaultInterpreterPath to ~/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/, restarted vsc (not sure it is useful) and then I could choose from Poetry env list.

Comment: in my case, I didn't need to do that. However, if I create my env directly in the vsc terminal, it doesn't appear directly in my available kernels. I have to restart my vsc before it appears in my list.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are not using the same kernel as the environment.
(Assuming you have your poetry setup up and running)
You can do it by adding jupyter to your poetry environment by `poetry add --group dev jupyter`
then run - `poetry run jupyter notebook`

Please see this [link](https://hippocampus-garden.com/jupyter_poetry_pipenv/) for full usage.